# Is there a way use itertools.product as a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-itertools

The title might not be worded the right way, but I've got a function that takes a list as an input and outputs a value. Let's say I want to iterate the function over all possible combinations of a binary list of a given length, n. I know that `(itertools.product([0,1], repeat=n)` is the best way to handle all combinations, but an `itertools` object creates each different combination as a tuple, not a list. So in order to feed them into the function, they each need to be converted to a list, which now negates the effectiveness of using `itertools`.

Is there any way around this? An alternative to, or way to manipulate, the `itertools` function that allows each entry to act as a list? Or is the only way to alter the initial function to take tuples instead of lists?

My primary desire for this is to combine the properties of a list with the generative properties of itertools. I would prefer to find a fix like this that minimizes compute resources, as opposed to re-writing the rest of my code for the sake of modularity that I may not fully utilize.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the result to a list to feed it to a function? Please show us the code you're trying to write.

Comment: _Do_ they need to be turned into lists? Tuples are also sequences. And `list(t)` works where you really do need to convert (e.g. applied via `map`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function must take a list, you can convert the individual combinations to a list when needed. You still get the benefits of product, i.e., you're not storing all the combinations in memory at any given point, you're only converting one combination to a list at a time.

```
for combination in itertools.product([0,1], repeat=n):
    function_that_must_take_a_list(list(combination))
```